# Codeigniter MySql Database Connection Issue

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

The settings in \config\database.php for remote database connectivity are the following:

> // Remote Server settings 
> $db['default']['hostname'] =
>   'abc.com'; 
> $db['default']['username'] = 'admin';
>   
> $db['default']['password'] = 'password';
>   
> $db['default']['database'] = 'mydatabase';

But accessing the webpage via browser it gives the following error.

```
A Database Error Occurred

Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.
```

Is there any issue with hostname? Other credentials are correct but I am not sure about hostname! I provided the IP address of my website also but both give the same error. The hostname of mysql database will be different than the website? although I hosted the database on the same server using CPANEL.

Comment: In my experience, when I have had this problem it's a firewall issue on the remote machine.

Comment: If the database is hosted on the same server as the website, then you can just use "localhost"

Comment: Really thankful for your solution of "localhost". Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the database is on the same server, use localhost for the hostname.